How Do I Get Started With ATtiny85 in 2024?
I recently purchase a ATtiny85 from ebay https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/375425498292 as I wanted to make a diy volume controller for my computer, but its become apparent that's its more difficult than its supposed to be programming this board,
I managed to download drivers from GitHub as the main  http://digistump.com/ site has disappeared and is no longer working,
I found the drivers here: https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore/blob/v2.0.0-devThis-is-the-head-submit-PRs-against-this/Installation.md as well as here: https://github.com/digistump/DigistumpArduino/releases/download/1.6.7/Digistump.Drivers.zip
I installed them and I have it show up in my device manager:

For the Arduino IDE I'm running the version 2.3.2 as of today, Ive added the following package json files:
I had to upload the package.json file to a gist so I could use it https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MrJoshFisher/5704ae7e640a7ea1cec135647397f979/raw/74eabc3f644a770f91f5815f2f5d9f6b1430ad49/package_drazzy.com_index.json
The only version I can find that works of "ÄTTinyCore by Spence Konde" is version 1.3.2 as every version after that fails to download and doesnt work.
So after ive done that, I opened the example Blink file assigned the Pin as from the documentation I found on the Attiny85, and I got the following errors:
"A programmer is required to upload" - Short answer had to click Upload Sketch with Programmer "Arduino as ISP" also Tried "USBTIny" but end up getting another error "avrdude: Error: Could not find USBtiny device (0x1781/0xc9f)"
I'm running windows 11
I've watched several videos, tried multiple different solutions but it all seems to be varying things which could be the issue, so not 100% on what solution actually works,
So I am asking here in case anyone had a working setup.
Cheers

it's not digitastump.com ... you can use archive.org to look at archived pages

Thanks @jsotola for reminding me of the Wayback machine; the archived page gives a 302 but redirects to the github file I've noted in my answer.

These 'ATtiny85 boards' are the generic name for a project known as DigiSpark. (Source: I backed the Kickstarter for the DigiSpark ~10 years ago, so I did use them many years ago; the following is mostly from memory).
The original DigiStump (creators of the ATtiny85-based DigiSpark) website appears to have disappeared. So the board profile at http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json is no longer available.
Fortunately it is also in DigiStump's github repository at https://github.com/digistump
A URL that can be added to the additional boards URL is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digistump/arduino-boards-index/master/package_digistump_index.json
You will probably want to use the Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz) profile.
To upload the sketch, unplug the board, Press Ctrl-U and when prompted, plug the board back into the computer; this is how the bootloader is recognised.

I've just tested this and it all works as expected. The onboard LED is connected to pin 1 (on the board I have, which appears the same as OP's link except it is blue instead of black).

Are you using any specific programmer?

Finally Got it working cheers, added the json, found the package managed to get a blink working!

To clarify, for anyone else that may see this question: The programmer (for the DigiSpark board profile) is effectively the bootloader on the DigiSpark itself and no separate hardware is needed. The  Spence Konde board profile noted by OP will need separate programmer hardware.
